# setting a promise to an external variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that returns a promise (I believe, I'm new to javascript) which I'm trying to set to a variable `mxY`. I've written my functions like this:

```
function maxYvalue2() {
    return Rpt_scn_cost_v.find({filter: { where: {scenario_id: $stateParams.id}}}).$promise.then(function(response){
        var maxYvalue = 0
        for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            var currMaxYvalue = parseFloat(response[i].cur_cost) + parseFloat(response[i].tgt_cost);
            if (currMaxYvalue > maxYvalue) {
                maxYvalue = currMaxYvalue
            };
        }
        console.log("yVal: " + maxYvalue)
        return maxYvalue;
    });
};

var mxY = maxYvalue2().then(function (response) {
    console.log("fnc: ", response);
    return response;
});


console.log(mxY);
```

and my console shows this, where `mxY` seems to log a `{$$state: Object}`:

```
reports.controller.js:99 d {$$state: Object}
    $$state: Object
        status: 1
        value: 78820.3574413
        __proto__: Object
      __proto__: Object
reports.controller.js:88 yVal: 78820.3574413
reports.controller.js:94 fnc:  78820.3574413
```

from what I understand so far, the `.then` in `maxYvalue2()` is returning a promise, which is why I get back `$$state.Object`, but what I need to do is "unwrap" the promise when it resolves, is that right or am I completely off here? And then I set it to the variable?

------EDIT---------

I'm trying to get the result of `maxYvalue2()` to go here...change `yDomain: [0, 100000]` to `yDomain: [0, mxY]` in the highlighted area below:

```
function maxYvalue2() {
    return Rpt_scn_cost_v.find({filter: { where: {scenario_id: $stateParams.id}}}).$promise.then(function(response){
        var maxYvalue = 0
        for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            var currMaxYvalue = parseFloat(response[i].cur_cost) + parseFloat(response[i].tgt_cost);
            if (currMaxYvalue > maxYvalue) {
                maxYvalue = currMaxYvalue
            };
        }
        console.log("yVal: " + maxYvalue)
        return maxYvalue;
    });
};

var mxY = maxYvalue2().then(function (response) {
    console.log("fnc: ", response);
    return response;
});


console.log(mxY);


    $scope.options_scn_cst = {
            chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 40,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){ return d.x; },
                y: function(d){ return d.y; },
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                dispatch: {
                    stateChange: function(e){ console.log("stateChange"); },
                    changeState: function(e){ console.log("changeState"); },
                    tooltipShow: function(e){ console.log("tooltipShow"); },
                    tooltipHide: function(e){ console.log("tooltipHide"); }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: '',
                    tickFormat: function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %y')(new Date(d)); }
                },
                yDomain: [0, 100000], //<======change the 100000 to the var mxY
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: '$ / month',
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format('$,.0f')(d);
                    },
                    axisLabelDistance: -10
                },
                callback: function(chart){}
            },
            title: {
                enable: true,
                text: 'Scenario Costs Over Time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                enable: false,
                text: 'Put your Subtitle here.',
                css: {
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
                }
            },
            caption: {
                enable: false,
                html: 'Put your Caption Here.',
                css: {
                    'text-align': 'justify',
                    'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: What do you mean by `unwrap`? Your promise and the console.log seems to show expected values.

Comment: Move all code that needs the value in a `then` callback. That's the only way to "unwrap" it.

Comment: ok...so I moved the `$scope.options_scn_cst` inside of the `then()`, but now it seems like I can't access `$scope.options_scn_cst` now...

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a promise, there is no way to synchronously unwrap it. Welcome to the land of asynchronous programming!

You can only retrieve the resolution of a promise inside of a `then()` clause (or a `catch()` clause if there is an error).

When you call `console.log(mxY);` you are accessing the promise itself in the same tick that you have created the promise. The promise has not yet been able to resolve. Since JavaScript is single threaded, you can never access the resolution of a promise, except asynchronously.

So, yes, you must use a `then()` clause. And thankfully, promises provide a mechanism to chain `then`s.

You could do this:

```
maxYvalue2().then(function (response) {
    console.log("fnc: ", response);
    return response;
}).then(function (response) {
    // do something
    return newResponse
}).then(function (newResponse) {
    // do something
    return notherNewResponse
}).then(function (notherNewResponse) {
    // etc
    return notherNotherNewResponse
});
```

What this is showing is that you can chain your promises and use them to perform some fairly complex asynchronous computation.

Comment: so do you set for example `var foo = response` inside of the `then()`? I guess where I'm confused is if `foo` is set inside of `then()`, how do you call `foo` outside of `maxYvalue2`?

Comment: Answer is that you can't. The value arrives asynchronously. You need to acces the value through callbacks and promise chains.

Comment: ok...so does that mean I need to put the logic that I'm using the external `var` for inside of the `then()`? I added some more code to show where I want to put the result of `maxYvalue2` in the code. Sorry if these are pretty basic questions...

Comment: That's correct. Since the result is only available inside of the `then()` method, you can only mutate the `$scope` inside of `then()`.

Comment: so is there is no way to get it outside of the `then()`, correct?